# Porqué ocurre esto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Me he encontrado con un problema que se podría resumir en el siguiente código:

```js
const a = ' '
const r = /\s+/gm;
const b = r.test(a);
const c = r.test(a);
const d = r.test(a);
const e = r.test(a);
const f = r.test(a);


console.log(b, c, d, e, f)
```

la salida en consola es: true false true false true

en vez de: false false false false false

porqué ocurre esto en llamadas consecutivas a un misma función y con los mismos parámetros?
porque cambia en las llamadas pares respecto de las impares.

Comment: Quítale el `g` y funcionará como esperas. Al especificar la bandera `g` la expresión regular guarda internamente el último match, y en la próxima invocación comenzará por ahí.

Comment: Aunque la pregunta es interesante, efectivamente es duplicada (a la que @JaimeMenéndez hizo referencia). El título de la otra pregunta es, ahora, más descriptivo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado la solución: se debe a que el parámetro global **g** de la expresión regular deja el puntero de búsqueda en la última posición encontrada, y desde ahí inicia la búsqueda en la siguiente llamada (llamada par), al no encontrar nada se reinicia a cero en la siguiente (impar) y así sucesivamente. Para la identificación de cadenas es mejor no usar el parámetro **g**. Lo he encontrado [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739136/consecutive-calls-to-regexp-test-fail-for-pattern-with-global-option).